# What's the difference between paint remover and stain remover?

Tags: stain-removal

***Background.*** I have a wooden surface that is stained, lacquer/sealed.  I want to remove the stain/lacquer/sealer to apply a different stain.  I will also be sanding or chipping slightly from the wood to get the old stain.  So, the stain remover will basically allow me to chip less wood (save the original size).

***Question.*** Can I use any paint remover for this job?  Or is there a difference between what's sold as stain remover and a paint remover?

Comment: I would _strongly_ recommend you review the [Finishing](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finishing) and [Refinishing](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/refinishing) tags at the [Woodworking.se] sister site. _Loads_ of good info there on finish identification and methods for removal, as well as reapplication when you're back to bare wood, or as close as you'll get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took quite a while for me to find a product designed to remove "wood stain finishes" as opposed to products that are designed to remove various stains from wood. An important distinction. A bit to my surprise, it turns out that there *are* "wood stain finish removers" on the market, (I see one example available from my local BigBox store) but I've never used them before. The "classic" way to remove wood stain from wood is with sandpaper.

The lacquer/sealer is likely to respond well to a stripper because they are surface finishes, but because the nature of a stain is to soak into the wood, I'm skeptical about how well a chemical "stain remover" would actually work on the embedded pigments.

The BigBox [instructions and accompanying photos](https://www.homedepot.com/c/ah/how-to-remove-wood-stain/9ba683603be9fa5395fab9014e504953) seem to indicate that the removal is far from complete, but it may be enough for re-staining a darker color or freshening the color without darkening it too much.

You might want to follow the chemical stripper with a wood bleach and almost certainly some sanding to remove as much of the embedded color as possible. Depending on how much color you want to remove the chances of getting away without sanding are pretty slim.

Answer (score 2):

Paint tends to be a surface treatment, stain goes below the surface.

So paint remover is designed to soften the paint layer.

Stain removers - which I have not found, need to affect below the surface. Perhaps why thorough sanding is used to remove stained wood.